# License Error when Reading or Writing to Esri Geodatabase in FME

Tags: fme-form, license, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-license-manager

After Upgrading  ArcGIS from 10.2.2 to 10.3, FME 2015 fails to run any workbench and shows this massage.

“Unable to perform licensing related tasks. Please ensure that ArcGIS is correctly installed
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
... Last line repeated 2 times ...
|ERROR |
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
|ERROR |
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details”

[image]

The massage shows that the FME 2015 Do not recognize the ArcGIS 10.3 licence while my ArcGIS is working probably, I just found a link that talks about the same issue which is:

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Error_Unexpected_Behavior/FME-cannot-read-or-write-to-Esri-Geodatabase-license-error-messages

and I just followed the instuction form ESRI about licensing ArcGIS product with Environment Variable but nothing helps

[image]
[image]

Have any one upgraded to ArcGIS 10.3 and faced the same problem ?

Comment: I'd ask Safe. I suspect that ESRI have changed the licensing setup and so FME isn't compatible with 10.3; probably fixed in the next release if that's the issue.

Comment: Hi Jonathan,                                                please have a look at this                 http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Notes-on-FME-and-ESRI-Versions-and-Compatibility

Comment: Good find. I went looking for that but couldn't find it. In that case I'd definitely contact your FME support.